# How do I store Chrome extension data securely?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension documentation [explicitly states](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) that `storage.sync` data is not encrypted: "Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted."

What is the recommended method to:
1) Save persistent data securely (ie, no loss from restarting browser or logging into Chrome on a different device)
2) Without transferring anything to my server (unnecessary in my case and want to give user full data control)

Comment: There's no secure storage in client browser.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** - that's the thing.

Google Chrome docs warns about all the ways of storing data using extensions are insecure. Basically, all the data sources may be compromised: 
localStorage, Cookies, WebSql, Chrome.storage. So the only way you can store data securely without extension user to be able to reach it is to send it over to secure server. 
You can use Ajax, XMLHttpRequest in pure JS to make it happen.

P.S. I assume Google has restricted this possibility on purpose. Keep in mind, that all of your content scripts are working in [isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). 
This is all indicates that Google wanted to make sure the extension are transparent for user and will not hide anything or bring damage to one's experience.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Am I missing some benefit here? How is it good for users to have data forced to either (1) have full data control but without encryption or (2) lose data control when it's transferred to someone's server for encryption?

Comment: Well, first of all I'm not working in Google to justify )) Therefore, I assume that extensions are designed to work as a kind of overlay to extend user experience. User experience doesn't require the data to be encrypted. You will never persuade me ) You may need to store some user preferences, but not something personal which requires encryption. And for sure you're right that there's always a risk to lose data during transmission.

Comment: What about the chrome.identity API?  I mean there needs to be a semi-secure  way to store the authentication information to allow you to transfer that data to a server or the whole house of cards falls down.

Comment: I can see it's still under development - so there's a risk using it in production, however at some point of time - it will be a way to store some critical data in the browser. Still I have some concerns in regards of Google policy of cleaning 3rd party cookies by the end of 2022. All these policies are pointed to preserve some PII hygiene . As you may assume there is some conflict in these 2 approaches. Saving PII within the browser and chrome.Identity API usage.

Comment: People interested in this topic may want to follow this issue on the w3c/webextensions repository: [Proposal: browser.secureStorage API](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/154)