# How Do You Install and Access Database When a Chrome Extension is Added?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that needs to store data in a local database without accessing the database directly. I am very new to chrome extensions and their limits, so I do not know what I can use to download the database/where I should download it and what I should use to access the data.

Comment: Chrome has localstorage that you might want to use

Comment: @Shane_Yo I need the data to be very permanent. From what I read, keeping the data in localstorage could result in it being erased unintentionally.

Comment: Do have software on the server and can you install something there that can talk to this storage?

Comment: @Shane_Yo The idea was to have everything be local, so a javascript file would be installed with the database to communicate with it. However, I am not sure if there is a way to install the javascript and SQL files when the chrome extension is added.

Comment: Extensions are basically like privileged web pages, they run in browser environment so they can use only DOM storage and chrome.storage which is not a database so the closest thing to database is IndexedDB and the deprecated WebSQL. You'll probably have to rethink the entire thing.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for clarifying! I really had no idea what the limits of extensions were, so it's good someone told me about this before I got too far. I think I'll just stay with the extension but do everything I need on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

To view the options for browser databases / data storage , look in the Application tab in Chrome dev tools:

[image]

You can find tutorials on how to use javascript to access 'Local Storage', 'Session Storage', 'IndexedDB', 'WebSQL' and 'Cookies' in places like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm .  An example from that page:

To create and open a database, use the following code −

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Hope that gets you started.  I've used these in the past and I'm just starting a new extension project that will store users' data and can update this if I find a particularly good resource.

Comment: It may also be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61488705/2455159 answered recently about extension data security.